# How to get standard xUnit v2 XML file with test results

Tags: c#, xml, xunit.net

I've created a C# xUnit Test Project through Visual Studio 2019 and using Selenium for UI testing.  This 'xUnit Test Project' appears to create a .netcore app.

Packages installed (most recent versions of each):

- xunit (2.4.1)
- xunit.runner.visualstudio (2.4.3)

When running tests through Visual Studio, I get the output in Test Explorer fine, but I don't get any XML output.  I've tried running via command line and specifying '--logger' but this is giving me an XML (trx, renamed as xml) file that looks totally different to the standard xUnit v2 XML structure I was expecting.

I'd like to get the standard xUnit v2 XML output so that, down the line, I can import this into other CI or test management tools e.g. Jenkins, xray, etc, or write a custom XSL-T stylesheet for more advanced HTML output.

I tried installing 'xunit.runner.console' but 'xunit.console.exe' refused to run.  There could be security policies on my work laptop at play here for exe files, as the xunit.console.exe seemed to be located elsewhere, nowhere near my project files (MVC projects I've created in the past had packages with the project, .netcore seems to put them somewhere else?)

Running:

```
dotnet test --logger "trx;LogFileName=TestOutputResults.xml"
```

or

```
dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName~XUnitTestProject1.TestClass1.Test1 --logger "trx;LogFileName=TestOutputResults.xml"
```

results in the following formatted XML file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestRun id="" name="" runUser="" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Times creation="" queuing="" start="" finish="" />
  <TestSettings name="default" id="">
    <Deployment runDeploymentRoot="" />
  </TestSettings>
  <Results>
    <UnitTestResult executionId="" testId="" testName="" computerName="" duration="" startTime="" endTime="" testType="" outcome="Passed" testListId="" relativeResultsDirectory="">
      <Output>
        <StdOut>Info: Randomly generated test data</StdOut>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
  <TestDefinitions>
    <UnitTest name="" storage="" id="">
      <Execution id="" />
      <TestMethod codeBase="" adapterTypeName="" className="" name="" />
    </UnitTest>
  </TestDefinitions>
  <TestEntries>
    <TestEntry testId="" executionId="" testListId="" />
  </TestEntries>
  <TestLists>
    <TestList name="Results Not in a List" id="" />
    <TestList name="All Loaded Results" id="" />
  </TestLists>
  <ResultSummary outcome="Completed">
    <Counters total="1" executed="1" passed="1" failed="0" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
    <Output>
      <StdOut></StdOut>
    </Output>
  </ResultSummary>
</TestRun>
```

but the standard xUnit v2 format from what I can find online (https://xunit.net/docs/format-xml-v2 & https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Taking+advantage+of+xUnit+XML+reports) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assemblies timestamp="07/31/2018 14:58:48">
    <assembly name="C:\Users\smsf\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\xUnitDemo\xUnitDemo\bin\Debug\xUnitDemo.DLL" environment="64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000 [collection-per-class, parallel (1 threads)]" test-framework="xUnit.net 2.3.1.3858" run-date="2018-07-31" run-time="14:58:47" config-file="C:\Users\smsf\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\xUnitDemo\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.4.0\tools\net452\xunit.console.exe.Config" total="15" passed="14" failed="1" skipped="0" time="0.257" errors="0">
        <errors />
        <collection total="2" passed="1" failed="1" skipped="0" name="Test collection for xUnitDemo.SimpleTests" time="0.070">
            <test name="xUnitDemo.SimpleTests.PassingTest" type="xUnitDemo.SimpleTests" method="PassingTest" time="0.0636741" result="Pass">
                <traits>
                    <trait name="test" value="CALC-2" />
                    <trait name="requirement" value="CALC-1" />
                    <trait name="labels" value="core UI" />
                </traits>
            </test>
            <test name="xUnitDemo.SimpleTests.FailingTest" type="xUnitDemo.SimpleTests" method="FailingTest" time="0.0059474" result="Fail">
                <failure exception-type="Xunit.Sdk.EqualException">
                   <message><![CDATA[Assert.Equal() Failure\r\nExpected: 5\r\nActual: 4]]></message>
                    <stack-trace><![CDATA[ at xUnitDemo.SimpleTests.FailingTest() in C:\Users\smsf\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\xUnitDemo\xUnitDemo\SimpleTests.cs:line 30]]></stack-trace>
                </failure>
            </test>
        </collection>
    </assembly>
</assemblies>
```

Could anyone explain what I've done wrong, or if I'm being stupid and missed doing something obvious please?

What do I need to do / what command do I need to run to generate standard xUnit v2 XML files with my test results?

I've spent a few days using Google, DuckDuckGo, looking through xunit.net and the github code, to try and figure this out and can't find anything, it's driving me crazy.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, getting this to work seems to have gotten way easier since you asked this question.

I was able to get it working by

1. installing [the XUnitXml.TestLogger nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XunitXml.TestLogger)
2. then running `dotnet test --logger "xunit;LogFileName=TestOutputResults.xml"`

Credit goes to [the official vstest docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/main/docs/report.md#test-loggers) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this question, I figured it out.  Still don't know why dotnet test gives a different output, but now I can get standard xUnit v2 XML formatted output.

As stated in my original question, despite a lot of searching online, I couldn't find an answer.

The problem was caused by multiple issues:

1. Security policies at work meant that xunit.console.exe was being blocked from running.  I discovered this by setting up a new personal test machine and running a sample project on it and it ran fine.
2. Once I was able to run this, trying to run my tests gave me a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly` error.  In [xunit.console.runner fails with filenotfoundexception #1950](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1950) bradwilson confirms that xunit.console does not work with .net core, despite there being folders in the nuget package tools folder for it.  It was a leftover for the now deprecated 'dotnet xunit' command, but was left "in the package at the .NET Team's request".  That explained why there was no xunit.console.exe file in the core folders of xunit.runner.console nuget package and, as I had tried, running the last .net framework 4.7.2 xunit.console.exe wouldn't work with the .net core test project.

So I created a new xUnit Test Project using the same namespace as I had used before, set the target framework as .net 5 and then followed the instructions on https://xunit.net/docs/getting-started/netfx/cmdline replacing the .csproj file contents to match:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">    
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference
        Include="Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies"
        Version="1.0.0"
        Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETFramework' ">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; 
          contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.4.1">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; 
                     contentfiles; analyzers; 
                     buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

I then copied all my tests, page object models, etc, over (as namespace was the same) over to the new project, installed all the additional nuget packages I required and ran the command again:

```
~/.nuget/packages/xunit.runner.console/2.4.1/tools/net472/xunit.console.exe bin/Debug/net48/SampleProject.UITests.dll -xml "SampleProject.UITests.xml" -html "SampleProject.UITests.html"
```

and got the standard xUnit v2 XML output I needed.

My next step is to follow the instructions for 'Setting up a unit test MSBuild target' as I know the CI pipeline we were using for MSTest can run the 'dotnet .....' command fine.