# Xunit - How to create a report with test results for every testcase

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, xunit, xunit.net

I would like to create a report about a test run with details for every [xUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test)-test that was executed.

The report should include

| Test Name | Assert Message | Result | Execution Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Login_is_Success | Error should be NULL | pass | 0.16ms |
|  | AccessToken.length > 8 | pass | 0.16ms |
| Login_is_failure | AccessToken should be NULL | pass | 0.36ms |
|  | Error.length > 0 | pass | 0.36ms |

#### What did i try?

[How to get standard xunit v2 xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68928327/how-to-get-standard-xunit-v2-xml-file-with-test-results) recommended to add XunitXml.TestLogger, which i did.

```bash
dotnet test --logger:xunit
```

The above creates an XML file

```xml
<test name="Foo.Tests.ColorPriceTests.ColorPrice_As_Expected" // fqf Testname
      type="Foo.Tests.ColorPriceTests"  // class ColorPriceTests
      method="ColorPrice_As_Expected" // method ColorPrice_As_Expected
      time="7.1"  // execution time
      result="fail" //  execution result
> ...
```

The xml contains

1. test name `LoginTest.Login_is_Success`
2. result `Pass`
3. execution time - i assume `time=0.169...`

But it lacks the assert messages

### Question

1. What needs to be done, to configure dotnet test to include the `assert message`?
2. <strike>A first step to use the xml above to create an html page that includes all but the assert message would be ok as well.</strike> Done but not ideal - see Cumbersome fill-in below
3. How would you configure [xunit.net](/questions/tagged/xunit.net) to create a report?

### What do i have?

#### Example tests

```cs
public async Task Login_is_Success()
{            
   var client = new Client();
   var loginResponse = await carConfigClient.Login();     
   // how to include the assert message into the report?       
   Assert.True(String.IsNullOrEmpty(loginResponse.Error), 
          "Error should be NULL");
   Assert.True((loginResponse.AccessToken.Length > 8), 
          "Acces Token should have more than 8 characters");
}

[Fact]
public async Task Login_is_Failure()
{        
   var client = new Client();   
   var loginResponse = await carConfigClient.Login("Basic wrongCreds");
   // how to include the assert message into the report?
   Assert.True(String.IsNullOrEmpty(loginResponse.AccessToken), 
          "AccessToken should be NULL");
   Assert.True((loginResponse.Error.Length > 0), 
          "Error.length should be greater than 0 characters");
}
```

#### Cumbersome fill-in

My [current fill-in solution is quite cumbersome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465232/819887)

- it requires to have an option to host the xml-file on localhost
- it requires xsl-manipulation.
- And the assert-message is still missing.

#### What is missing?

The xml above provides 1 to 3 but the assert message (4) is not included. Also the xml is no end user friendly report.

What i would like to have is a detail of every test result similar to the [playwright](/questions/tagged/playwright) [html test report](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/running-tests#test-reports)

[image: playwright Test Reports]

If one could see [details of a test execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2JPj.jpg) this would be a nice to have.